# Detect if Lightning Record Page is dirty in headless action LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have an LWC that serves as a headless quick action on the record page for a custom object. Users are inline editing the record, then clicking the button for the quick action before saving their changes. Is there a way to detect if they have made changes to the record page before calling the server-side Apex code in my invoke() method? I tried accessing the CurrentPageReference info from the lightning/navigation module, but it contained nothing helpful and didn't change between when the page was loaded and the user made an inline edit. You can also see I tried notifyRecordUpdateAvailable() and refreshApex on the page reference, but neither caused the Lightning Page to prompt the user to save or discard changes.

Basic code in JS file:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import ApexMethod from '@salesforce/apex/ApexClass.ApexMethod';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { notifyRecordUpdateAvailable } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class BtnRenewalAcceptRenewal extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [Custom_Field__c] }) targetRecord;
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    getPageReferenceParameters(currentPageReference) {
       if (currentPageReference) {
          console.log(currentPageReference);
          this._currentPageReference = currentPageReference;
       }
    }

    _currentPageReference;

    @api invoke() {
        //refreshApex(this._currentPageReference);
        console.log(this._currentPageReference);
        //notifyRecordUpdateAvailable([{recordId: this.recordId}]);
        refreshApex(this.targetRecord);

        let fieldVal = getFieldValue(this.targetRecord.data, Custom_Field__c);
        ApexMethod ({ prop: [this.recordId] })
            .then(ret => {
                // shows a success toast

                 //this line triggers built-in UI prompt to save or discard record
                 //but the apex code has already run on the old values of the record
                refreshApex(this.targetRecord); 
            })
            .catch(e => {
                // shows an error toast
            })
    }
}
```